# Heim joints with zerk fittings

Tags: power-steering, lubrication

On my truck I have heim joints setup in the steering to provide additional strength. Currently I have a 3/4 by 3/4 heim with teflon coatings, and with the mud and dirt where I live, they are getting harder to maintain over time.

I have considered replacing them with heim joints that have grease zerks instead, would this solve my issues regarding keeping up with the constant lubrication?

[image: Heim joint with zerk]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely. The great thing about having the zerks is when you put fresh grease in, the old grease comes out. With the old grease comes any dirt and grime which may have collected. This should keep your heim joint in good stead. Most heim joints are completely rebuildable, meaning you can take them apart, clean them, regrease, then put them back together. You may want to try this route before you try replacement.